# How to create many http servers into one app?

Tags: go

I want create two http servers into one golang app. Example:

```
    package main

    import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func helloOne(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello world one!")
}

func helloTwo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello world two!")
}

func main() {
    // how to create two http server instatce? 
    http.HandleFunc("/", helloOne)
    http.HandleFunc("/", helloTwo)
    go http.ListenAndServe(":8001", nil)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8002", nil)
}
```

How to create two http server instance and add handlers for them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need to create separate `http.ServeMux` instances. Calling `http.ListenAndServe(port, nil)` uses the `DefaultServeMux` (i.e. shared). The docs for this are here: http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewServeMux

Example:

```
func main() {
    r1 := http.NewServeMux()
    r1.HandleFunc("/", helloOne)

    r2 := http.NewServeMux()
    r2.HandleFunc("/", helloTwo)

    go func() { log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8001", r1))}()
    go func() { log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8002", r2))}()
    select {}
}
```

Wrapping the servers with `log.Fatal` will cause the program to quit if one of the listeners doesn't function. If you wanted the program to stay up if one of the servers fails to start or crashes, you could `err := http.ListenAndServe(port, mux)` and handle the error another way.

Comment: second instance go log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8002", r2)) does't start. When i go to localhost:8002 the webpage is not available.

Comment: You're only running the log.Fatal calls in their own Goroutines. The calls to ListenAndServe still happen on the Main Goroutine and will block.

Comment: Fixed it. Hammered it out on my phone. Should work now. The empty `select{}` is a quick way to block indefinitely.